# How to get rid of the grey selection border in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8

I'm working on a project and use JavaFX 8 for the GUI. When I click the text inside a tab of a tabpane, a thin grey box appears around the text as seen in the image below. When I click somewhere else it disappears. Does anyone know how to get rid of this box? Preferably using CSS.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

The CSS:

```
 .tab-pane {
 -fx-background-insets: 0;
 -fx-padding: 0;
}

.tab-pane .headers-region {
    -fx-padding: 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
}

.tab-header-area {
 -fx-padding: 0;
 -fx-background-insets: 0;
}

.tab-header-background {
    -fx-background-color: #9a3838;
}

.tab {
    -fx-background-color: #8b3333;
    -fx-padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    -fx-background-radius: 0px;
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-font-size: 14px;
}

.tab:top {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
}

.tab:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #b54343;
}

.tab:selected {
    -fx-background-color: #c24848;
}

.tab Label {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

.tab #SearchField {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the css you are using for the TabPane?

Answer (score 3):

The grey rectangle is a `Region` with a style class `.focus-indicator`, you can hide it with:

```
.tab-pane:focused > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab:selected .focus-indicator {
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the CSS file:

```
.tab-pane:focused > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab:selected .focus-indicator {
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
}
```

I found it in the modena.css file. Which contains CSS specific to JavaFX-8.

[modena.css](https://code.google.com/p/javafx-demos/source/browse/trunk/javafx-demos/src/main/resources/modena/Modena.css?r=73)